# Change 'origin' of .toggle() animation in JQuery

Tags: css, jquery

When using .toggle() to animate an element, I have found that the element always originates from and dissapears to the left side of the page, regardless of it's margins and alignment set by CSS. I have buttons on the left ad right of a web page that each open a small panel. The buttons on the left look fine when .toggle is called on their panels, because the animation originates from that side of the page. However, for the right buttons, the panels animate from the left, crossing the entire page to the right. They end up in the right place, but is it possible to have them originate from different points?

UPDATE: A dumbed-down example, here: http://jsfiddle.net/tMaJe/

Comment: You would have to provide some sort of example (maybe with http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/tMaJe/
I simplified the page to the main content div and one right panel. The animation on left panels works the same, but appears on the left and uses the CSS .leftpanel instead of .rightpanel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the effect of the animation for [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), [`.show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) or [`.hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) in jQuery. 
You can either use [`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or load [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) that will enable you to specify the effect for the above mentioned methods.

Example:

```
var $foo = $("#foo");

// with jQuery UI
$("button:first").click(function(){
    $foo.toggle("blind");
});

// without jQuery UI
$("button:last").click(function(){
    if ($foo.is(":visible")) {
        $foo.data("height", $foo.height()).animate({
            height: 0
        }, function(){ $(this).hide(); });
    } else {
        $foo.show().animate({
            height: $foo.data("height")
        });
    }
});
```

You can see this in action on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/JW3qf/).